# Print directly to a PyQt StatusBar

Tags: python, pyqt

I have two classes. One for my GUI in PyQt6 and the other one that executes a function. In my interface, I have a PyQt StatusBar and a Button. When I press the button, I call the other class. I would like to be able to modify the statusBar message from this new class.

Here is a small example of code to reproduce the situation.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Python")
        self.setGeometry(60, 60, 200, 100)

        self.statusBar().showMessage("This is status bar.")

        button1 = QPushButton(self)
        button1.setText("Button1")
        button1.clicked.connect(self.button1_clicked)

        self.show()

    def button1_clicked(self):
        a = OtherClass
        a.Add(100, 200)

class OtherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    def Add(a, b):
        print(f"{a} + {b} = {a+b}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

In this example, I want the statusBar to show the message `"100 + 200 = 300"`.
I know that it is possible to send the statusBar as an argument to the new class and use it. But I don't want to do that. I want my OtherClass to be empty of any PyQt elements.

It is possible to use `print` to replace `logging.info`.  Is the same possible for `statusbar().showMessage` and `print`?

Comment: Why don't you just return the result instead of printing it?

Comment: Here is a small example with one print to do, but my OtherClass, is supposed to be much bigger. A return wouldn't work for what i have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to a callback.

You can simply use a `lambda` and pass it into the `Add` method as a 3rd parameter.

For example:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Python")
        self.setGeometry(60, 60, 200, 100)

        self.statusBar().showMessage("This is status bar.")

        button1 = QPushButton(self)
        button1.setText("Button1")
        button1.clicked.connect(self.button1_clicked)

        self.show()

    def button1_clicked(self):
        a = OtherClass
        a.Add(100, 200, lambda x: self.statusBar().showMessage(x, 10000))

class OtherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def Add(a, b, cb_func):
        cb_func(f"{a} + {b} = {a+b}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Or an even easier solution would be to do what is suggested in the comments, and simply return the value.

Comment: I did not think of the CallBack. This may work. Thank You.